# Use non-built-in bash commands without modifying .bashsrc

Tags: bash

I'm working on cluster and using custom toolkits (more specifically SRA toolkit). In order to use it, I fist had to download (and unpack it) to a specific folder in my directory.

Then I had to modify .bashsrc to include the following segment:

```
# User specific aliases and functions
export PATH="$PATH:/home/MYNAME/APPS/SRATOOLS/bin"
```

Now I can use a stuff from SRATools in bash command line, e.g.

```
prefetch SR111111
```

My question is, can I use those tools **without** modifying my .bashsrc?

The reason that I want to do that is because I wrote a .sh script that takes a long time to run, and my cluster has Sun Grid Engine job management system, and I submitted my script to it, only to see the process fail - because a SRA Toolkit command I used was unrecognized.

EDIT (1):

I modified the location where my prefetch command is, and now it looks like:

```
/MYNAME/APPS/SRA_TOOLS/bin
```

different from how it is in .bashsrc:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/MYNAME/APPS/SRATOOLS/bin"
```

And run what @Darkman suggested (put IF THEN ELSE FI and under ELSE put export). The output is that it didn't find SRATools (because path in .bashsrc is different), but it found them under ELSE and script is running normally. Weird. It works on my job management system.

Thanks everybody.

Comment: well, can you not add this line `PATH="$PATH:/home/MYNAME/APPS/SRATOOLS/bin"` to your long-running .sh script?

Comment: I did. I added an IF (finds command) THEN ELSE FI subsection, and under ELSE I put that line, defaulting to PATH. However, I still got an error "prefetch, command not found"

Comment: Probably because of the way you ***find*** that program. You can use `command` for that e.g. `if command -v prefetch 2>/dev/null 1>&2; then ...; else "export your path";  prefetch SR111111; fi`.

Comment: @Darkman Would you mind clarifying? Under ELSE, do I put  `export PATH="$PATH:/home/MYNAME/APPS/SRATOOLS/bin" `? I'll try that first thing in the morning.

Comment: You could call prefetch with its full path, no need for PATH when doing that.

Comment: @ivan199415 Yup, that's right.

Comment: @Darkman I did just that, and checked the error output of my job. It didn't find the command, but it find prefetch either.

Comment: @Nic3500 I'll try that, but I have more commands I need to rub from SRATOOLs in my script and I do not want to type  that out constantly

Comment: You could put the path in a variable (like `binpath="/something/path/"`) and use that when calling a command (like `"$binpath"/command`).